# update query with join on two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `customer` and `address` tables.

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM addresses a,
     customers b
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

returns 474 records

For these records, I'd like to add the `id` of `customer` table into `cid` of `address` table.

**Example**:
If for the first record the id of customer is 9 and `id` of address is also 9 then i'd like to insert 9 into cid column of address table.

I tried:

```
UPDATE addresses a,
       customers b
SET a.cid = b.id
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

this is Postgres UPDATE JOIN format:

```
UPDATE address 
SET cid = customers.id
FROM customers 
WHERE customers.id = address.id
```

Here's the other variations: http://mssql-to-postgresql.blogspot.com/2007/12/updates-in-postgresql-ms-sql-mysql.html

Answer (score 5):

Using table aliases in the join condition:

```
update addresses a
set cid = b.id 
from customers b 
where a.id = b.id
```

Comment: this method avoids problems if you are joining two tables with the same name from different databases

Answer (score 3):

Officially, the SQL languages does not support a JOIN or FROM clause in an UPDATE statement unless it is in a subquery. Thus, the Hoyle ANSI approach would be something like

```
Update addresses
Set cid = (
            Select c.id
            From customers As c
            where c.id = a.id
            )
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From customers As C1
                Where C1.id = addresses.id
                )
```

However many DBMSs such Postgres support the use of a FROM clause in an UPDATE statement. In many cases, you are required to include the updating table and alias it in the FROM clause however I'm not sure about Postgres:

```
Update addresses
Set cid = c.id
From addresses As a
    Join customers As c
        On c.id = a.id
```

Comment: Postgres does not require including the updating table in the `FROM` clause. In fact, the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) states that ***"the target table must not appear in the `from_list`, unless you intend a self-join"***. Therefore it may lead to wrong results to mention the table in the `FROM` clause unless you want the table to join with itself. **N.B.** You can alias the updating table in the `UPDATE` clause.

Comment: WARNING - Executing an update in this format will target all rows in the addresses table.

Comment: @RyanWilliams - Both formats will update all rows that have a customer, yes. That was the request.

Comment: @ADTC - An Update clause that excludes a From clause *is the ISO standard way* that Update statements must be written. Thus, it makes sense that Postgres allows for this. The *inclusion* of the From clause is not ISO standard but is supported in some fashion by most database vendors including Postgres. As you can see from the selected answer, you can include the target table in the update clause even if you are not using a self-join.

Comment: @ADTC - In my answer, my point about including and aliasing the target table refers to when you are using a join of some sort. I.e., it probably isn't allowed to write `Update addresses From customers Where ...`.

Comment: @Thomas I wanted to clarify that including the updating table again in the `FROM` clause will cause a **self-join** in Postgres (while other DBs may behave differently). It is to help unwary developers from causing an unintended join (most likely a horrible Cartesian join) of the table with itself when doing this in Postgres. This is **clearly stated** in the Postgres documentation (and the question is tagged for Postgres). FTR, Postgres allows, and in fact **requires** you to write `Update addresses From customers Where ...` if a self-join is not intended.

Comment: @Thomas Basically, I would like to see you expand your answer and split the last example into two. One for Postgres (without the updating table repeated in `FROM` clause) and the other for whichever DBMS works differently (with the updating table repeated in the `FROM` clause). And remove the *"however I'm not sure about Postgres"* ambiguity `:)`

Comment: Just a note here, when I tried doing this using a VIEW consisting of two Foreign Data Wrappers (FDWs), I could not get all the records to update, it said something to the effect of a single record was updated.  Instead what I had to do was pull the VIEW into a table (`CREATE TABLE  table_name AS`)  on the local postgres server, and then do the `UPDATE` using `table_name` and one of the FDWs.

Answer (score 0):

```
update addresses set cid=id where id in (select id from customers)
```

Comment: A `join` combines columns from one or more tables, a `in` is just a list of ids (even if  you get them from another `select`).    This answer is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: There is no biding between  customers and addresses.

Answer (score -3):

Try this one

```
UPDATE employee 
set EMPLOYEE.MAIDEN_NAME = 
  (SELECT ADD1 
   FROM EMPS 
   WHERE EMP_CODE=EMPLOYEE.EMP_CODE);
WHERE EMPLOYEE.EMP_CODE >='00' 
AND EMPLOYEE.EMP_CODE <='ZZ';
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question (and it's invalid SQL as well)