# Postgres mass update query (convert from mysql)

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I need to convert a query to postgresql. I precise this query works on mysql.

```
UPDATE cache_implementation n
INNER JOIN cache_compared compared ON n.compared_id = compared.nid
LEFT JOIN cache_implementation ncp ON (compared.parent_id = ncp.compared_id AND n.feature_id = ncp.feature_id)
INNER JOIN cache_feature feature ON n.feature_id = feature.nid
LEFT JOIN cache_implementation nfp ON (feature.parent_id = nfp.feature_id AND n.compared_id = nfp.compared_id)
SET n.parent_through_compared_id = ncp.nid, n.parent_through_feature_id = nfp.nid
```

When I try to execute it, I have a syntax error near
LINE 2:                  INNER JOIN cache_compared compared ON n.com...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is that the actual error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [update query with join on two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815953/update-query-with-join-on-two-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE cache_implementation
SET cache_implementation.parent_through_compared_id = ncp.nid, 
    cache_implementation.parent_through_feature_id = nfp.nid
FROM cache_implementation n
INNER JOIN cache_compared compared ON n.compared_id = compared.nid
LEFT JOIN cache_implementation ncp ON (compared.parent_id = ncp.compared_id AND n.feature_id = ncp.feature_id)
INNER JOIN cache_feature feature ON n.feature_id = feature.nid
LEFT JOIN cache_implementation nfp ON (feature.parent_id = nfp.feature_id AND n.compared_id = nfp.compared_id)
WHERE cache_implementation.compared_id = n.compared_id
  AND cache_implementation.feature_id  = n.feature_id;
```

Comment: Check that I did the where clause correctly, I took a guess based on what I saw.

Comment: It seems to have made it, except I need to remove the WHERE clause and cache_implementation in the SET. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to remove the where clause? You need to join the table your updating with the table that is being joined to the records you are targeting.  That's what FROM cache_implementation n gives you.

Comment: Yes sorry, I realize it like one hour after and it was too late to edit my post.
You're absolutely right.