# how to update a table which joined using two tables, with new data

Tags: mysql

I have joined two tables with using Left outer join. I added a new a column to that new table.

How can I update that column with new values?

I tried to update that table with following query. But it is not working.

```
UPDATE devicechoice
SET devicechoice.Flag= 'True'
WHERE Employee_ID = '1001';
```

Comment: my schema is devicemanager. I have created two tables which are called devices and users. Then i created a new table by joining those two tables which is named as device choice. And i added new column to that which is called Flag. now i need to update that column with new values

Comment: see This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815953/update-query-with-join-on-two-tables).meet your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank all for the help. I found my error. Actually it was a problem in mysql server. it has come to the toggle situation. So I used this query.

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE devicechoice
SET devicechoice.Flag= 'T'
WHERE Employee_ID = '1001';

Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this syntax:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET column_name='value'
FROM Table1 
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

I have send you the general syntax as you have not provide the database detail so exactly i can't send you the query but this will help you. Refer:http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/30/sql-server-update-from-select-statement-using-join-in-update-statement-multiple-tables-in-update-statement/

If you don't get the solution then send me the complete details i will surely help you.All the best !!!

Comment: Give the entire query so i can check it.