# Best ways to apply Joins inside a Update Query in Postgreql (performance wise)

Tags: postgresql

I Want to update a table column after checking multiple conditions on multiple tables

Answer (score 1):

I think set from is more feasible at often and is faster than subquerying.See this understandable example.

```
 UPDATE t_name AS t 
    SET T.attr1 = r.attr2
    FROM any_list AS r
    WHERE t.anylist_id = t.id
```

Joins are executed by the RDBMS with an execution pattern such that to optimize data loading and processing, unlike the sub-query where it will run all the queries and load all their data to do the processing.
More on subqueries can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-subquery.html)

The subquery will generally only be executed far enough to determine whether at least one row is returned, not all the way to completion like in joins. It is unwise to write a subquery that has any side effects (such as calling sequence functions); whether the side effects occur or not may be difficult to predict.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well they perform, but I see at least the following two possibilities:

- A subquery
- [UPDATE SET FROM - syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2815969) (can be found in [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-update.html), too)